# How to decompose a Cocoa application into reusable functional parts?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, service, soa

Suppose I'd like to **decompose an application into functional parts**. E.g. a customer data management part, a text-formatting part, an invoicing part. I'd prefer be such parts somehow simple but complete applications.

Furthermore, suppose I'd like to design parts, which may be **reused in new or other applications**. E.g. the customers data part could be used in a CRM solution, but as well in an invoicing application.

I'm in search for something like a [**compound documents**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_document) **architecture**.

**Questions...**

- Which **Apple / Cocoa technology** should I use to create such functional parts?
- Would it be possible to enclose in a function part the **data-store and the UI**?
- If true, how could one use a UI of one application / part in another application?
- Does such infrastructure / framework / technology exist for Cocoa?

**Probably simpler Questions...**

Suppose I have two applications `A` and `B`. `B` **provides an editor** for some `B`-related data. Suppose `B`'s editor is fully contained in an NSView subclass. Thus, the edit controls are fully contained inside the subclass.

- May I somehow make B's NSView's subclass live appear in an A's windows.

My aim is **not** to live embed **arbitrary** stuff of `B` in `A`. It would be OK to instrument `A` and `B` by a certain common protocol.

**Of interest...**

I'm aware of [Cocoa's distributed objects technology](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DistrObjects/DistrObjects.html), which allows applications to talk to each other even if they run on different compute nodes. But since **DO simply provides a transport mechanism**, it isn't a solution for my high-level decomposition question.

While an application can **register URL schemes** to be called from other applications, they do not provide enough functionality - since URLs are one way from caller to called. See [here](http://iphonedevelopertips.com/cocoa/launching-your-own-application-via-a-custom-url-scheme.html) and [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Apple provides this [Plug-In Architectures document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/LoadingCode/Concepts/Plugins.html) - but focuses on **one application's own plug-ins**. Furthermore [Apple's CFPlugin document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFPlugIns/CFPlugIns.html) might be of interest too (still valid?).

[Matt Gallagher](http://cocoawithlove.com/) provides a short overview of various options in [Five approaches to listening, observing and notifying in Cocoa](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/06/five-approaches-to-listening-observing.html). Except sending notifications through [**NSDistributedNotificationCenter**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDistributedNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html), all options are application-local. Thus, the Apple document [Notification Programming Topics](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Notifications/Introduction/introNotifications.html) is of interest, but more as a l**ow-level object transport mechanism**.

I'm pretty sure, that some years ago, a **group of software developers/companies** tried to implement some kind of **dynamic data exchange** at the Cocoa level. Their framework didn't come from Apple. Unfortunately, I don't remember their framework's name.

[How to open a new application within an existing NSView on OS X?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6816542/how-to-open-a-new-application-within-an-existing-nsview-on-os-x)

**Influenced by...**

My question is influenced by [**intents** of the Android SDK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html). Citation:

*'An Intent provides a facility for performing late runtime binding between the code in different applications. Its most significant use is in the launching of activities, where it can be thought of as the glue between activities. It is basically a passive data structure holding an abstract description of an action to be performed.'*

**Very loosely related...**

- Web-related: [InfoQ article](http://www.infoq.com/news/2012/02/the-object-network#.TzBDoHMYwbU.twitter) about [The Object Network: Linking up our APIs](http://the-object.net/).
- A 1993 article by [Dave Winer](http://scripting.com/) about [IOA, an Interactive Object Architecture](http://scripting.com/frontier/sdk/macbirdplugins.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each "part" would probably constitute a framework or library. A framework is a special kind of library that encapsulates dynamically linked code, headers, and resources into a bundle; a library is either dynamically or statically linked and is essentially a bare binary file.

A framework or library can contain pretty much any code an application can, and an application can call any code in one. For more information, see the [Dynamic Library Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/DynamicLibraries/000-Introduction/Introduction.html) on ADC.

If what you're looking for is something that can be loaded into another application to gain access to your application (in whole or in part) then on Mac OS X, this would still be accomplished through a framework/library. On iOS, it's not possible since inter-process communication is extremely limited, but a self-contained static library is still an option for code sharing.

Comment: Thank your for this proposal too! DyLibs are definitely of interest. Unfortunately, I wonder, if sandboxing rules allow to load DyLibs from other applications, which provide certain functionality.

Comment: Offhand I'm not sure but I'd lean toward "not allowed."

Answer (score 5):

You should try looking into XPC Services if you're on OSX Lion 10.7. You can have different XPC Services and your main application executable all in the same Xcode project. The idea is to modularize your design and have each service with its own system privileges. You should also be able to share those XPC services between projects. Apps talk to XPC services through interprocess communication via Grand Central Dispatch.

In fact, if you're creating an application you intend on selling in the App Store, Apple encourages that you use XPC for privilege separation. There is a an Apple sandbox tutorial that helps you begin a sample project that uses XPC, and if you follow from the beginning you get a good example how to do so.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW2

Of course, privilege separation isn't the only reason to break up your application to use these services. I think it well suits what you are trying to achieve. I would assume it's possible to put UI in a service, but have never tried it yet. Talking back and forth between service and application should be the same regardless of UI, I would think.

**Creating XPC Services**
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingXPCServices.html

Comment: Thank your for this interesting proposal! XPC seems to be the first-class solution for >10.7+ pure-data processing parts. Unfortunately, XPC doesn't provide support for GUIs.